# Is there a way to efficiently transform sparce matrix into series?

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I'm trying to compute the tf_idf of a corpus of texts, and then store the results into a pandas dataframe as a series. However, when I try to do so, I run out of working memory when transforming the sparce matrix into a normal one. My code up to now is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import scipy.sparse as sp
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords



text = np.array(df["text"])
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
X = X.toarray()

tfidf = []
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    print(i)
    s = pd.Series(X[i], index=vectorizer.get_feature_names_out())
    s = s[s!=0].sort_values(ascending=False)
    tfidf.append(s)
    
newdf = df
newdf["tf_idf"] = tfidf
```

The main problem comes in X.toarray(), as the resulting error is extremely big (I think it said around 1Tb, Im working with 1 million + short texts).

Could someone lend me a hand?

EDIT: I have solved it, so in case anyone has the same problem I used the .toarray() over the individual lines of the matrix, so something like this

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(text)

tfidf = []
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    print(i)
    s = pd.Series(X[i].toarray(), index=vectorizer.get_feature_names_out())
    s = s[s!=0].sort_values(ascending=False)
    tfidf.append(s)
```

Comment: did you try to change the type of the variable, for example np.float8

Comment: I've tried, but it is still much bigger than what my pc can store

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer, and after one day you can accept it.